# Identificar regiones aisladas en una matriz (error en algunos casos especiales)

Tags: javascript, matrices

**Necesito que se separen las diferentes regiones o "islas" formadas por 1s** dentro de una matriz de cualquier dimensión. Mi ejemplo parecía funcionar correctamente pero **hay algún caso "especial" como el siguiente que no trabaja bien. Debería detectar 2 elementos o regiones y sin embargo se "confunde" y encuentra 3** (cuando la 2 y 3 deberían ser la misma). Podéis correr el ejemplo para ver más claro lo que explico.

```js
var matrix = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
];

var contFilas = matrix.length;
var contColumnas = matrix[0].length;
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var sz = 20;
var regions = [];
var regionCollection = [];

canvas.width = sz * contColumnas;
canvas.height = sz * contColumnas;
ctx.fillStyle = "silver";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

for (var y = 0; y < contFilas; y++) {
    var regionline = [];
    regions.push(regionline);

    for (var x = 0; x < contColumnas; x++) {
        var pixelRegion = 0;
        regionline[x] = 0;
       


        if (matrix[y][x] === 1) {
            // check previous row
            if (y) {
                if (matrix[y - 1][x]) {
                    pixelRegion = regions[y - 1][x];
                } else if (x && matrix[y - 1][x - 1]) {
                    pixelRegion = regions[y - 1][x - 1];
                } else if (x + 1 < contColumnas && matrix[y - 1][x + 1]) {
                    pixelRegion = regions[y - 1][x + 1];
                } 
            }

            // check current row
            if (x && matrix[y][x - 1]) {
                pixelRegion = regions[y][x - 1];
            }

            // if not connected, start a new region
            if (!pixelRegion) {
                regionCollection.push([]);
                pixelRegion = regionCollection.length;
            }
            // remember region
            regionline[x] = pixelRegion;
            regionCollection[pixelRegion - 1].push([x, y]);

            // paint it
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.fillRect(x * sz + 1, y * sz + 1, sz - 2, sz - 2);
        }


        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText(pixelRegion, x * sz + 8, y * sz + 13);

    }
}
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(regionCollection);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>getUserMedia</title>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas></canvas>
 <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**¿Cómo puedo corregir esto? no consigo solucionar el error...** Podría solucionarse con una función recursiva que el recorrer la matrix se llame para comprobar en cada coordenada si tiene 1s a su alrededor (arriba, abajo, izquierda, dcha y diagonales). Estoy estancada y no sé cómo solucionar el error

Comment: Puedes poner `matrix[2][7]=0` y ver si te encuentra 4 islas? Si te encuentra 4 regiones ya sé dónde está el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema viene cuando la celda a partir de la que tiene que coger la región está debajo. Como únicamente se comprueban las celdas superiores y de la misma fila va a interpretar que es una región nueva cuando no es así.

Una solución podría ser la de utilizar una función recursiva para crear la región completa a partir de una celda. Cuando encuentres una celda activa que no pertenece a ninguna región se crea una nueva región y se van añadiendo las celdas continuas de forma recursiva.

Algo así:

```js
var matrix = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
];

var contFilas = matrix.length;
var contColumnas = matrix[0].length;
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var sz = 20;
var regions = [];
var regionCollection = [];

canvas.width = sz * contColumnas;
canvas.height = sz * contColumnas;
ctx.fillStyle = "silver";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

function createRegion(board, row, col, regionNum, region){
  // Si no viene array para la región lo creamos
  region = region || [];
  // Añadimos la celda a la región
  region.push([col, row]);
  board[row][col] = regionNum;
  // Si alguna celda contigua tiene valor -1 se añade a la región
  // llamando a la función recursiva
  if (board[row-1]){
    if (board[row-1][col-1]===-1) createRegion(board, row-1, col-1, regionNum, region);
    if (board[row-1][col]===-1) createRegion(board, row-1, col, regionNum, region);
    if (board[row-1][col+1]===-1) createRegion(board, row-1, col+1, regionNum, region);
  }
  if (board[row][col-1]===-1) createRegion(board, row, col-1, regionNum, region);
  if (board[row][col+1]===-1) createRegion(board, row, col+1, regionNum, region);
  if (board[row+1]){
    if (board[row+1][col-1]===-1) createRegion(board, row+1, col-1, regionNum, region);
    if (board[row+1][col]===-1) createRegion(board, row+1, col, regionNum, region);
    if (board[row+1][col+1]===-1) createRegion(board, row+1, col+1, regionNum, region);
  }
  // Devolvemos la región con las celdas añadidas
  return region;
}

// Crea un array igual que matrix con valores 0 y -1
var regionline = matrix.map(y => y.map(x => -x));
var regionCollection = [];

for (var y = 0; y < contFilas; y++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < contColumnas; x++){
    // Si el valor es -1 es una nueva región. Llama a la función recursiva a partir de esa posición
    if (regionline[y][x] === -1){
      regionCollection.push(createRegion(regionline, y, x, regionCollection.length +1));
    }
    // Dibuja la celda
    if (regionline[y][x] > 0){
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(x * sz + 1, y * sz + 1, sz - 2, sz - 2);
    }
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText(regionline[y][x], x * sz + 8, y * sz + 13);
  }
}
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(regionCollection);
```

```html
 <canvas></canvas>
 <div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás comprobando si pertenece a la misma región del siguiente modo:

Compruebas primero las 3 posiciones de la fila superior:

- Cuadro diagonal superior izquierda
- Cuadro superior al actual
- Cuadro diagonal superior derecha

Y posteriormente compruebas la fila actual (Aquí sólo miras una posición, ya que por la derecha aun no has pasado):

- Cuadro izquierdo al actual

**El problema ocurre** cuando la matriz llega y lee la posición `matrix[6][1]`. Si te fijas, después de realizar todas las comprobaciones listadas arriba, ninguna resulta positiva. Por lo que está asignando una nueva región!

NOTA: La fila `matrix[8][]` se establece a región `3` porque compruebas en último lugar el "Cuadro izquierdo al actual". 
Es decir, aunque encuentre una región llamada `2` encima, después, cuando mira a su izquierda es sustituida por `3`.

Answer (score 1):

El elemento

"x": 1,
  "y": 6

Está rodeado de ceros en la fila de arriba, a su derecha y a su izquierda. Aunque la región 2 se propaga hacia abajo y la derecha, no se propaga en sentido inverso.

```js
var matrix = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
];

var contFilas = matrix.length;
var contColumnas = matrix[0].length;
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var sz = 20;
var regions = [];
var regionCollection = [];

canvas.width = sz * contColumnas;
canvas.height = sz * contColumnas;
ctx.fillStyle = "silver";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

for (var y = 0; y < contFilas; y++) {
    var regionline = [];
    regions.push(regionline);

    for (var x = 0; x < contColumnas; x++) {
        var pixelRegion = 0;
        regionline[x] = 0;
       


        if (matrix[y][x] === 1) {
            // check previous row
            if (y) {
                if (matrix[y - 1][x]) {
                    pixelRegion = regions[y - 1][x];
                } else if (x && matrix[y - 1][x - 1]) {
                    pixelRegion = regions[y - 1][x - 1];
                } else if (x + 1 < contColumnas && matrix[y - 1][x + 1]) {
                    pixelRegion = regions[y - 1][x + 1];
                }  
            }

            // check current row
            if (x && matrix[y][x - 1]) {
                pixelRegion = regions[y][x - 1];
            }  

            // if not connected, start a new region
            if (!pixelRegion) {
                console.log('New region on',{x:x, y:y});
                regionCollection.push([]);
                pixelRegion = regionCollection.length;
                console.log('pixelRegion on',{x:x, y:y}, 'is '+pixelRegion);
            }
            // remember region
            regionline[x] = pixelRegion;
            regionCollection[pixelRegion - 1].push([x, y]);

            // paint it
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.fillRect(x * sz + 1, y * sz + 1, sz - 2, sz - 2);
        }


        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText(pixelRegion, x * sz + 8, y * sz + 13);

    }
}

regionCollection.forEach(function(region,index) {
   console.log('region '+index, JSON.stringify(region));
});
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```